# Is it possible to run an SSD in a windows enviroment/compatibility using Bottles in Linux?

Tags: linux-mint, windows, wine, compatibility, winetricks

I'm new to Linux and as you can tell, I'm migrating from Windows with lots of Windows software. Eventually, I learned about Wine and Bottles which made me wonder if, instead of re-installing every program, I could somehow let the SSD loaded with my software run in a Windows environment/compatibility setting so I can avoid the tediousness of re-installation. Is it possible? If it is, is there a guide you recommend I should follow?

Thanks for your time in advance. If you have any questions, let me know!

Cheers!